# TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: angular

I am new to this community i have the following problem in angular i am getting this error
Compiled with problems:X
[Foto del error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSO36.png)

I don't know what is causing this error that is throwing me
I am new to angular

```
  Guardar(persona: Persona) {
    this.service.createPersona(persona)
      .subscribe(data => {
        alert("Registrado correctamente...!!!");
        /*Swal.fire(
          'Good job!',
          'You clicked the button!',
          'success'
        )*/
        this.router.navigate(["listar"]);
      })
  }

<div class="container col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Personas</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Nombres:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Apellidos:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button (click)="Guardar()" class="btn btn-success ml">Guardar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not written in English, does not include a reproducible piece of code and shows the actual error only in an externally hosted image.

Comment: Also, the error in the title is a different one then the one in the image. The (image) error is self-explaining; the function expects an argument and you’re not providing it (persona)..

Answer (score 1):

The code here:

```
<button (click)="Guardar()" ...>
```

Is calling the Guardar() function and not passing anything in.

The function is expecting that you pass in a persona.

```
Guardar(persona: Persona) { ... }
```

So you'll either need to change the function to *not* require a passed in argument or pass the required argument in the button click.